# How to find the amplitude of the membrane of the speaker if the the input voltage is known?

Tags: vibrations

Can anyone tell me what are the relevant pieces of information that are required to find the amplitude of a speaker membrane for a particular input ac signal frequency and voltage amplitude? Could you also show the method by which I can achieve that? Do I need to do an energy balance? Does that mean I would require to know the elastic modulus of the material of the membrane? Or is there any other predefined parameter of the speaker usually provided that I can use to get around that kind of calculation approach?

Comment: It's complicated. I'd just measure it.